# Mixing argon2/HKDF to generate both password hash and encryption key?

Tags: encryption, hash, argon2

I am trying to use a user password in my application to both generate a password hash (for authentication) and to derive a secret key to encrypt user data.

Using argon2 is an expensive operation so i only want to call it only once when the user is logging in, and because i need to store the hash in the database to authenticate the user, then i cannot use this hash as a secret key nor derive a key from this hash as an attacker could do the same is the database is leaked.

My idea was to call Argon2id **once** to generate a 256-bit hash, then use HKDF to generate two 256-bit keys using different info tags (`auth` and `secret`).

```
pass_hash  = argon2id(password, salt)
auth_hash  = hkdf(pass_hash "auth")
secret_key = hkdf(pass_hash, "secret")
```

The app would use the `auth_hash` to build a custom password hash similar to the argon2i one and save it to the database, something like:

```
$argon2id-hkdf$v=19$m=65536,t=1,p=2,i=auth$4yKXVET50Z+XXfq5HZuzXQ$6zOk2Tyay+dJcBMyXPEdvwlJzckRfhmnBgRdzMzkfeU
```

In this example i changed the algorithm name and included the HKDF info tag to the hash string so everyting needed is in one place.

The `secret_key` would be used as is for the secret key in AES function to encrypt/decrypt user data. I don't save this key in the database.

For the string hash, i would derive `auth_hash` when the user is logging it and compare it with the one in the database using a constant-time comparison function. If it matches then i derive the `secret_key` and log in the user.

For the questions:

- Can i use any short string as the info tag of the HKDF function? It is secure?
- Should i be using the output of argon2id directly as the input of HKDF?
- The output of HKDF is secure to be used as a AES key?
- Is there any problems that i am not aware of with my custom password hash?
- Using Argon2/HKDF in this way is secure?
- This seems like something that must already exists (both authenticate and encrypt stuff with only a password). There is an alternative or what i am doing is good enough and secure?

Comment: HKDF uses Extract and Expand [Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298). You can use HKDF directly. Keep in mind that, you cannot increase the entropy of the password source. You can make only harder to bruteforce... I cannot see the benefit of Argon2id here except the low entropy source where the iteration, and memory hardness of Argon2id matter. So, the crucial point is the quality of the users' passwords.